$f$ is discontinuous and $\int_a^x f(t)\text{d}t$ is differentiable
Find a function $ f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $, integrable on $[a,b]$ and
$$ F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) \, dt $$
such that there exists $ x_0 \in [a,b]$ and  $x_0$  is point of essential discontinuity
and $F(x)$ is differentiable in $x_0$.
I tried to do something with $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ when $x \ne 0$, and $f(0) = 0$  but I don't know how to show that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{\int_{0}^{h} \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) \, dt}{h} \right) = 0
$$
maybe I am looking at the wrong function?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

$f(0)$ isn't defined. Try more elementary function such as step functions.

Answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127903/derivative-of-int-0x-sin1-t-dt-at-x-0/2132923#2132923 and see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3627847/f-is-integrable-on-a-b-and-fx-int-ax-ft-dt-if-f-is-differ?rq=1 for a more complete discussion of this problem.
